# Proving $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\log{p_n}} {\log n} = 1$

Tags: prime-numbers

How do I show:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\log{p_n}} {\log n} = 1$$

where $p_n$ is the $n$th prime number without using the Prime Number Theorem?

Some context: The reason I can not use the PNT (or at least the form one might try to use) is because this is actually what I am trying to prove, or rather a certain form of the prime number theorem. The PNT states that $\pi(n) \sim \frac n {\log n}$, i.e.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {\pi(n) \log n } n = 1$$

where $\pi(n)$ is the prime counting function.

Substituting $n \to p_n$ one has:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac {n \log p_n} {p_n} = 1$$

Now I would like to show that $p_n \sim n \log n$, i.e.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac {n \log n } {p_n} = 1$$

which requires the proof I am asking for.

Comment: Could you tell us your background. Along with where you encountered this question?

Comment: @GautamShenoy Updated the question

Comment: I think you can use the fact that $n<p_n<n^2$.

Comment: Second thought... that could only be used in order to prove limit $\leq2$.

Comment: I am guessing this is difficult then...

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to the prime number theorem.

Comment: @Asvin A proof that this is implied by PNT would be most helpful.

Comment: This page is quite good about general information on prime number estimates and provides references: https://primes.utm.edu/howmany.html

Comment: The wikipedia page is pretty good on information too - a little light on sources for minor details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It suffices to prove the PNT up to a multiplicative constant. This is much easier than proving the PNT and was in fact done by Chebyshev.

Actually something slightly weaker suffices. A good enough upper bound can be extracted from [the proof of Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_of_Bertrand%27s_postulate) (not Bertrand's postulate, really the proof), as explained [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/50017/232); you get $p_n \le C n \log n$ for some constant $C$. And of course $p_n \ge n$ suffices for the upper bound.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more how do you get the bound for $p_n$ from the lemmas on the other reply you link? Because yo get ir I'm using also Bertrand's postulate and I don't think that is the intended way on your answer.