# Prove by induction: $\forall n \in \mathbb{n}, n \geq 1 \Rightarrow 2^{2^{n}}-1$ is divisible by at least n distinct primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I tried to play around with $2^{2^{n + 1}} - 1$, such as splitting it to $2^{2^{n} \cdot 2} - 1$, but it didn't helped much. I am kind of stuck and don't know what to do next

Comment: Are you familiar with the difference of squares identity?  $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$...

Comment: @abiessu yes, but I don't see how it would help here.

Comment: So, in this case, take $a=2^{2^n}$ and $b=1$, this gives that $2^{2^{n+1}}-1=(2^{2^n}+1)(2^{2^n}-1)$.  What prime can divide both portions of this multiplication?

Comment: @abiessu Thank you so much, I got it.

Comment: @Charlie FYI, the proof to your question is given as "Proof 2" in the question text of [Different ways to prove there are infinitely many primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/50006/602049).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As guided in the comments, taking $2^{2^n}-1$ as a difference of squares allows for the $n+1$ term to be written as

$$2^{2^{n+1}}-1=(2^{2^n}+1)(2^{2^n}-1)$$

On the RHS, any prime which divides both of the factors must divide their difference, which is $2$.  But both factors are odd, so these factors are relatively prime to one another.